# In an OpenCV application, how do I identify the source of memory leak and fix it?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, opencv

I have a memory leak in my OpenCV application. Its a medium size application with a dozon of classes and a few thousands lines of code. Somehow, I managed to produce a large memory leak in my application that it eats away all of my 8gb memory in a few minutes. I am using OpenCV C++ 2.3 on Ubuntu 11.10 with CMake.

[image: An snapshot of how much memory is freed right after I terminate the app. I can watch the used memory go up to 4gig in a matter of a few minutes]

It is a hand tracking application and it process two video streams simultaneusly at a frame rate of around 15fps for each camera.

I tried using valgrind like below, but the output of valgrind is so huge that exceeds the amount of text shell can keep in buffer. I know I can save the output to a log file, but I was hoping to avoid the daunting task of reading through all of it. Here is the valgrind command I used:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./Gibbon
```

Here is the last few lines of valgrind output:

```
==3573== 5,415,576 (1,176 direct, 5,414,400 indirect) bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,571 of 2,571
==3573==    at 0x4C28F9F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3573==    by 0x5B2ACD0: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1)
==3573==    by 0x5A7FA9D: cvCreateImageHeader (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1)
==3573==    by 0x484538: CameraPGR::convertImageToOpenCV(FlyCapture2::Image*) (CameraPGR.cpp:212)
==3573==    by 0x483F52: CameraPGR::grabImage() (CameraPGR.cpp:134)
==3573==    by 0x473F86: start() (GibbonMain.cpp:368)
==3573==    by 0x4725CC: main (GibbonMain.cpp:108)
==3573== 
==3573== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3573==    definitely lost: 24,432 bytes in 33 blocks
==3573==    indirectly lost: 5,414,640 bytes in 15 blocks
==3573==      possibly lost: 2,314,837 bytes in 1,148 blocks
==3573==    still reachable: 496,811 bytes in 4,037 blocks
==3573==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3573== 
==3573== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3573== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3573== ERROR SUMMARY: 336 errors from 318 contexts (suppressed: 10 from 8)
```

What are some better ways that I can approach this problem? Are there some tools that can show me in a concise way what function calls are causing most of the memory allocations? If valgrind is the answer, I would appreciate some hints on how to use it in a more efficient way since I am totally new to this tool.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say you're probably allocating memory somewhere around `CameraPGR::grabImage()` and never freeing it.

Comment: I have looked at that function several times, cant find the issue there. I will do some more messing around with it tomorrow. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can improve the process of finding the root cause of a memory leak?

Comment: Without seeing any of your code it's really impossible to guess at what's going wrong.  Do you free the memory that is allocated in the above callstack?  If not, there's your problem.

Comment: Specifically, since you're calling `cvCreateImageHeader`, are you also calling `cvReleaseImageHeader`?

Comment: No I am not calling `cvReleaseImageHeader` since I am returning the image from the function. The image is then converted to `cv::Mat`. Once I am done using it in the main loop I call `image.release()` on it. Is that not enough to take care of releasing all the memory associated with this image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an answer, but a suggestion: Move from OpenCV C interface to C++. If properly used, it will minimize your chances for a leak, now and in the future. Its smart pointers embedded in the objects automatically free memory.

In the worst case, you'll have a performance penalty (too many allocs/deallocs), but those are easy to spot in a profiler.

The C++ interface is using

```
Mat intead of IplImage, 
Point instead of CvPoint, 
cv::function() instead of cvFunction.
```

And you do not have to declare pointers to images:

```
Mat src = imread("myfile.jpg");
Mat gray; // note that I do not allocate it. 
// This is done automatically in the next functions
cv::cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
imshow("Gray image", gray);
waitKey();
```

If you have some legacy code, or a third-party that uses the other interface, it's easy to convert back and forth:

```
Mat src(width, height, CV_8UC3);
IplImage* legacyImg;
legacyImg = &(IplImage)src;
```

Other datatypes (like `CvPoint`) are automatically converted. `CvSeq` is replaced by `std::vector<T>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Except the part that I read the image from the camera which I wrote about a year ago, I dont use C interface anywhere else. Since I discovered the C++ interface I have been using that constantly. But thanks anyway!