# Wanting to live-mirror video in OpenCV on OSX, not sure where to start

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, video-processing

If it isn't already obvious, this is my first day playing around with OpenCV. 
What I am hoping to do is mirror frame2, and then upsample it.

I am not sure how to use a matrix operation on these frames which are of type IplImage. How could I mirror my frame2, and then upsample it to the Webcam2 window? Below is my code:

```
 #include "cv.h" 
 #include "highgui.h" 
 #include <stdio.h>  



 // A Simple Camera Capture Framework 
 int main() {
   CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
   if ( !capture ) {
     fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
     getchar();
     return -1;
   }
   // Create a window in which the captured images will be presented
   cvNamedWindow( "Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   cvNamedWindow( "Webcam2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
   while ( 1 ) {
     // Get one frame
     IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
     IplImage* frame2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize (frame->width*2, frame->height*2), 
     frame->depth, frame->nChannels);
     cvPyrUp (frame, frame2);



        if ( !frame ) {
       fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
       getchar();
       break;
     }

     cvShowImage( "Webcam", frame );
     cvShowImage( "Webcam2", frame2 );
     // Do not release the frame!
     //If ESC key pressed, Key=0x10001B under OpenCV 0.9.7(linux version),
     //remove higher bits using AND operator
     if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
   }
   // Release the capture device housekeeping
   cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
   cvDestroyWindow( "Webcam" );
   cvDestroyWindow( "Webcam2" );
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean *transpose*, *rotate* or *flip* ?

Comment: Transpose. Basically, I want a matrix [1, 0, 1; 1, 0, 0; 1, 0, 0] to look like [1, 0, 1; 0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 1]. Does that clarify? I don't know how to perform matrix operations on live frames though.

Comment: That looks like a left-right flip (mirror image) - is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a neat function in OpenCV, called `flip()`. The C counterpart is named `cvFlip()`. And I am sure it will help you.

And I will also give you the advice I always give: Move from the C interface to C++! Much cleaner, much safer, much easier!

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585852/in-an-opencv-application-how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-memory-leak-and-fix-it/8591335#8591335) answer to see the differences between the two.

Comment: by the way, your code will crash at the first bad image. You must check that `frame` is not null exactly after you capture it, not after you do some processing.

Comment: I'm not sure how to move from the C interface to the C++ interface considering how poor OSX documentation is for OpenCV, but that flip() library is perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: I just added this line: `cvFlip (frame2, frame2, 1);`

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem to move to c++, all the functions are there, all the docs are there. I think you can just rename your IplImage* to MAt and cvFunc to cv::func,and it will work. Ans CvCapture to VideoCapture. You can try to define a `Mat myImg;` and see if compiles

Comment: Defining `Mat myImg;` throws a 
`imgld.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:`
`imgld.cpp:26: error: ‘Mat’ was not declared in this scope`
`imgld.cpp:26: error: expected ';' before ‘myImg’` I'm even compiling with g++, as per my previous question on here.

Comment: try cv::Mat img; and also check that you have included the core.hpp, not oly the core_c.h header

Comment: `#include`-ing `cv.hpp` instead of `cv.h`, and using `cv::Mat img;` worked. Thanks so much.