# Opencv: How to compute mirror of Rect vector

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a video processing project and need to find an ROI from the mirror of the source image.

The ROI coordinates are with respect to the mirror image, and I need to map it to the original source image. Is there any built in functions in opencv for this?

ROI is a rectangle and by *mirror image* I mean flipping the image with respect to the Y-axis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wanting to live-mirror video in OpenCV on OSX, not sure where to start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613881/wanting-to-live-mirror-video-in-opencv-on-osx-not-sure-where-to-start)

Comment: Indeed, that other question is about a left-right flip, which sounds like the same as mirroring by the y-axis. @OP: Can you confirm that it's a duplicate? Alternatively, add a few details to describe the difference?

Comment: no sir absolutely not the post you mentioned is all about mirroring the whole image by mine is about mirroring the roi boundary which is of rect type. The ROI boundary is computed from the mirror image of the src file but the the rectangle to be displayed is on the source file...so i need to flip the rectangle in order it to fit on the original source file

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
cv::Rect r;

for(int i=0;i<rectg.size();i++)
{
     r=rectg[i];
     r.x=rotated_img.cols-r.x-r.width;
     rectg[i]=r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[cvSetImageROI](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=roi#void%20cvSetImageROI%28IplImage%2a%20image,%20CvRect%20rect%29) is for setting the ROI region. here the `rect` is your desire region of interest. [cvGetImageROI](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=roi#CvRect%20cvGetImageROI%28const%20IplImage%2a%20image%29) is return the selected ROI rectangle.

```
void cvSetImageROI(IplImage* image, CvRect rect)
```

Comment: actually the i need the mirror of the ROI boundary...I got it and answered it...thanks..